# No sounds on Chrome 42 using the Web audio API

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, web-audio-api

When I try this simple source code :

```
<body>
  <audio controls src="http://webaudioapi.com/samples/audio-tag/chrono.mp3"></audio>

  <script>
    window.AudioContext = window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext;
    context = new AudioContext();

     var mediaElement   = document.querySelector('audio'),
         sourceMediaTag = context.createMediaElementSource(mediaElement);

    sourceMediaTag.connect(context.destination);

    mediaElement.play();
  </script>
</body>
```

The player starts but I haven't sound with Chrome 42 (it's ok with Chrome 41).
I also tried with an audio gain between the source and the destination, but nothing change.

Someone knows what happens ?

Comment: The audio resource probably does not have the required access-control headers.

Comment: I also tried this with the file in the same directory (<audio controls src="chrono.mp3">) and this is the same problem :(

Comment: If you've placed the file in the same directory and it's not working, then it's a bug in Chrome 42.  File a bug with a repo case.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this post](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=477692) I have to set a CORS policy in the media server AND set a "crossOrigin" parameter in the media (audio or video) markup.

Thanks for your help !